Firebase Auth with OIDC
At our company we have our own OpenID Connect server (built using OpenIDDict in C#). I've set the server up as an OIDC provider in Firebase Auth and it seems to work relatively well. I can extract the access token successfully like this:
final oAuthProvider = OAuthProvider('oidc.our-company-authentication')
    ..setScopes([
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "email",
        "offline_access",
        "roles",
        "our_app_scope",
    ]);

final credential = await _auth.signInWithProvider(oAuthProvider);
return credential.credential?.accessToken;

I can use the token to authenticate with our backend services which are not related to Firebase, but after some time (roughly an hour), the token stops working.
Usually we then have to use the refresh token to request a new access token, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this using the Firebase Auth SDK. I've had a quick look at some of the standard providers, but I couldn't find any mention of refresh tokens. Seemingly their tokens live forever. Or am I missing something?
Since we implemented our authentication server ourselves, it might be possible we're not handling a certain flow correctly. I'm wondering what Firebase Auth requires our server to be able to do in order to work correctly as an OIDC provider.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been struggling with this for a couple days now.
I'd love to hear from someone who has used Firebase Auth with a "non-standard" OIDC provider (aka. not the Google/Facebook/Twitter/... ones Firebase offers) successfully.
